# What happens if letter of recommendation to a university contains a wrong fact?

Tags: graduate-admissions, recommendation-letter, university

My teacher recently uploaded some letter of recommendations for post graduate applications but the letter was a generic one she typed for me and in the last paragraph, she wrote "applicant wants to apply to a masters program in USA....." but she uploaded the same document to UK universities as well including University of Oxford, Manchester, Sheffield.
Since this was a tiny mistake and she was using a generic letter for me to every university, will this be considered an issue to the university and can be rejected for admission?

Comment: This is not what I would call a "wrong fact".

Comment: What would be problematic if in your application to Oxford, it would say "I apply to this master program in Princeton".

Answer (score 7):

These kinds of mistakes happen all the time. Don't worry about it, just move on -- the people who will read the letters understand that these things happen.

Comment: Though, of course, it might be a little bit embarrassing for the person who wrote the letter.

Comment: I'll also add that i'm not sure how much weight people put on reference letters for master's degrees in the UK.